# Error: Undefined reference to WinMain

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que solicite escribir una cadena alfanumérica que tiene que ser almacenada en un arreglo y  tiene que identificar y escribir si es letra numero o espacio.

Por ejemplo:

h letra

espacio

1 numero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Uno de los principales problemas que tienes en el código que pusiste, es que al parecer no definiste la función int main() que es la que se ejecuta al iniciar el programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int max = 15;               //definimos el largo maximo de la cadena 
    char a[max];                //definimos la variable "a" para almacenar el dato ingresado
    cout << "Dime una palabra (Puedes usar números, letras y espacios):"; //muestra mensaje
    cin.getline(a, max);        //lee la linea ingresada y la almacena en a

    for(int i=0;i<max;i++){     //iniciamos un ciclo recorriendo toda la palabra

        if(a[i] == ' ')         //preguntamos si es espacio
            cout << a[i] << " Espacio"<<'\n';
                                //ahora preguntamos si es numero
        else if ((a[i] == '1') || (a[i] == '2')|| (a[i] == '3')|| (a[i] == '4')|| (a[i] == '5')|| (a[i] == '6')|| (a[i] == '7')|| (a[i] == '8')|| (a[i] == '9')|| (a[i] == '0'))
            cout << a[i] << " Numero"<<'\n';
        //ahora preguntamos si caracter especial
        else if ((a[i] == '*') || (a[i] == '+')|| (a[i] == '-')|| (a[i] == '#')|| (a[i] == '$')|| (a[i] == '(')|| (a[i] == ')')|| (a[i] == '@')|| (a[i] == '/')|| (a[i] == '.'))    
            cout << a[i] << " Caracter especial"<<'\n';
        else if (a[i]==NULL)    //preguntamos si no es nulo
            cout << "";
        else                    //Finalmente si no es espacio, ni numero, ni nulo asumimos que es letra
            cout << a[i] << " Letra"<<'\n';
    }

    cout << "Texto ingresado: " << a; //como verificacion imprimimos todo el texto ingresado
    return 0;
}
```

Prueba de salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para el futuro es muy importante que tomes en cuenta la recomendación de @gbianchi.

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre si el usuario introduce un caracter especial (p.e. `*`)?

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, se agregó una validación más para caracteres especial, aunque no estaba considerado en el dominio del problema planteado originalmente.